# "AccessViolationException was unhandled" error in C# Managed Code

Tags: c#, exception, .net-assembly, reflection.emit, il

I have new problem. My code:

```
.method public static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       3 (0x3)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  ldnull
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

C# code:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I'm generating this code via System.Reflection and System.Reflection.Emit classes. Does anybody known why this cannot works? Please help.

[image: My error]

One small question - should I generate constructor?

Comment: Just use il.DeclareLocal(...);

Comment: Protip: When writing IL, always use PEVerify after assembling. It would have told you this error straight away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to store a null in local 0 (`stloc.0`) but you don't actually have any locals defined.

You need to use the [`DeclareLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xffef4.aspx) method to define the local, then you can either pass that to the [`Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2725z44.aspx) overload that accepts a LocalBuilder (e.g. you can use that to emit the `stloc` opcode, followed by your LocalBuilder); or you can just carry on using `stloc.0` since you know there's only one local.